# Incremental changes to PDF

Tags: c#, pdf, pdf-generation

I have a PDF file saved as byte array in Database.  User can open this PDF from a website and can update it. Currently the whole new pdf is saved over the existing one. I am looking for a solution where,

- only the change bytes are saved and when the user retrieve new document

  i   want to recreate  the pdf from original one and then applying the changes.  I tried searching in internet for a solution/ idea on how to achieve this, i am not able to get any idea. Can some one throw a way  to achieve this using C#
  . This   solution will help me to track the changes that has happened over the time.

Comment: Could you save the file to a git repo?

Comment: There is a database. Need to save to that

Comment: Why does it **need** to be saved there? This is starting to feel like a XY Problem - https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem . Why do you want to store only the changed bytes and apply them? Why not just store each individual version of the pdf? Why not use a git repo (which solves most of this problem quite simply)? Why not store the files on the file system (so if there are 10 versions of the file just store the file 10 times on the file system)?

Comment: Currently i am saving each individual version of PDF. This will take a lot of space in database. So thinking was to have an incremental changes in the Database than whole pdf again and again

Comment: how can you replace only specific bytes in the database?

Comment: @ShloimeRosenblum, is there a solution to save incremental change of the pdf and recreate it from the original one.  This is my problem in summary

Comment: what is your problem with creating a new one?

Comment: The space. There are a lot of PDF ( in tens of thousands).  User may come and edit these using the application any time , when they want . There is no limit to that . The database is growing so fast , we need to think of alternate way to  get this changes . Some times the changes are just one character. Saving a 1 MB pdf again for just a char change :(

Comment: so save the new pdf over the old one

Comment: That's not the solution . How then will track the  changes

Comment: you can have a changes table with a foreign key to the pdf with the new bytes and the position to insert/replace it

Comment: I have all those in place.   I am trying to  find a better solution due to the space constraint

Comment: Why are you storing the files in the database rather than on S3 / file system?

Comment: Do you have control over the software the users use to update the pdf? If you have, you probably can make that software store changes in an "incremental update" section to the pdf.

Comment: Not really. control on that

Comment: A pdf is a binary file with things like offsets on byte count to other structures in the pdf. Have you even tried to see what difference you have? I will bet you will find that you cannot even solve that issue regardless of any database.

Comment: Thank you all for the feedback. I  am reaching to the conclusion that , currently the only option is to save to database each one.

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "can update it"? What edits/changes are your users doing? Is it just annotating and/or form filling?

Comment: annotating and or form filling

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the PDF standard specifically supports Incremental saves. A PDF file can contain any number of incremental saves, and can be specifically used for undo/redo and versioning. For instance, Incremental saving is how multiple people can cryptographically sign a PDF.

So you can keep the single original file, and then apply the modifications by simply appending the incremental save bytes to the original data.

Using [PDFTron PDFNet SDK](https://www.pdftron.com/) you can get the incremental save data using the following.

```
byte[] pdfdata = pdfdoc.Save(SDFDoc.SaveOptions.e_incremental);
```

pdfdata will contain the entire PDF, but the original bytes will be unchanged, and can be discarded, by getting the file size of the original PDF. So you can just store the additional bytes.

Then later you can load the original PDF, append the incremental save data you stored, and then load the PDF.

Note, if your users edits are only for annotations and form fields, there is an even simpler solution. Please see my comment to your original question.

Comment: Please read in the comments to the original question that the op has no control over the software the user uses to update the pdf. Thus, it is nice that PDFTron knows how to create incremental updates but this very likely does not help the op at all.